# How can I recreate the design presented here using TabView from the Community Toolkit NuGet Package? (link provided in the details)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm having issues reproducing the design presented in the link here: [Extending TabbedPage in Xamarin Forms](https://xamgirl.com/extending-tabbedpage-in-xamarin-forms/)

I created a project from scratch and used all the snippets provided. I've created a folder in the shared project and added a class that inherits TabbedPage. In the Android project I created a CustomRenderer folder that contains this last snippet that adds a line under the selected tab item:

```
public class ExtendedTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
    {
        Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage tabbedPage;
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
        private bool firstTime = true;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                tabbedPage = e.NewElement as ExtendedTabbedPage;
                bottomNavigationView = (GetChildAt(0) as Android.Widget.RelativeLayout).GetChildAt(1) as BottomNavigationView;
                bottomNavigationView.NavigationItemSelected += BottomNavigationView_NavigationItemSelected;
            }

        }
       
        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
           
            if (firstTime && bottomNavigationView != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Element.Children.Count; i++)
                {
                    var item = bottomNavigationView.Menu.GetItem(i);
                    if (bottomNavigationView.SelectedItemId == item.ItemId)
                    {
                        SetupBottomNavigationView(item);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                firstTime = false;
            }
        }

        void BottomNavigationView_NavigationItemSelected(object sender, BottomNavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            SetupBottomNavigationView(e.Item);
            this.OnNavigationItemSelected(e.Item);
        }

        //Adding line view
        void SetupBottomNavigationView(IMenuItem item)
        {
            int lineBottomOffset = 8;
            int lineWidth = 4;
            int itemHeight = bottomNavigationView.Height - lineBottomOffset;
            int itemWidth = (bottomNavigationView.Width / Element.Children.Count);
            int leftOffset = item.ItemId * itemWidth;
            int rightOffset = itemWidth * (Element.Children.Count - (item.ItemId + 1));
            GradientDrawable bottomLine = new GradientDrawable();
            bottomLine.SetShape(ShapeType.Line);
            bottomLine.SetStroke(lineWidth, Xamarin.Forms.Color.DarkGray.ToAndroid());

            var layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] { bottomLine });
            layerDrawable.SetLayerInset(0, leftOffset, itemHeight, rightOffset, 0);

            bottomNavigationView.SetBackground(layerDrawable);
        } 
}
```

To no avail though, if I run the project I cannot see any changes made to the TabbedPage.

If possible, I would like to recreate this design using TabView, as specified in the question title, or at least understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Can anyone help me with a solution? I can also provide the structure of my project to help you better understand my issue. Thanks in advance and any response is much appreciated.

Comment: Your link is broken

Comment: (I fixed their link.) *" I cannot see any changes made to the TabbedPage"* - are you saying that the tabs have their default look, as if xamarin is using its built-in renderer, instead of your custom one?

Comment: Yes, the tabs keep their default look. Apologies for not specifying, and also for the link, it now works properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [sample sources for that xamgirl article](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/ExtendedTabbedPageSample/blob/master/CustomTabbedPage.Android/ExtendedTabbedPageRenderer.cs), you'll see that they omitted an ESSENTIAL line `[assembly: ExportRenderer( ...` before the namespace declaration:

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;
using CustomTabbedPage.Droid;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedTabbedPage), typeof(ExtendedTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace CustomTabbedPage.Droid
{
    public class ExtendedTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
```

Without that line, Xamarin does not know to use your custom renderer.

Replace names of `ExtendedTabbedPage` and `ExtendedTabbedPageRenderer`, if you have different names.

Replace `CustomTabbedPage.Droid` with the namespace you have in your custom renderer file. Note that this must also be changed in `using ...;`

---

IMPORTANT: As written, this renderer WILL NOT BE USED for a `TabbedPage` class.

It will only be used for an `ExtendedTabbedPage : TabbedPage` class.

See article or its source for example of using it.

IIRC, to use it for ALL `TabbedPage`s in your app, change that essential line to:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(ExtendedTabbedPageRenderer))]
```